# Как исправить этот JavaScript код

Tags: javascript, html

Ожидаемое поведение: При нажатии на первую кнопку появляется вторая кнопка, а при нажатии на вторую кнопку вторая кнопка исчезает. Можете помочь мне исправить мой код. У меня при нажатии на первую кнопку появляется вторая, при нажатии на вторую вторая исчезает, но при повторном нажатии на первую вторая не появляется.

```js
let Mybutton = document.getElementById("first");
let Form = document.getElementById("myform");
let isNewButtonExist = false;
let str = `<button id = "second" > Вторая кнопка </button>`;
let NewButton;

Mybutton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (isNewButtonExist === false) {
    Form.innerHTML += `<button id = "second" > Вторая кнопка </button>`;
    isNewButtonExist = true;
  }

  if (isNewButtonExist === true) {
    NewButton = document.getElementById("second");
    NewButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      isNewButtonExist = false;
      NewButton.remove();
      NewButton = null;
    });
  }
})
```

```css
.MyWindow {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: calc(1000px + 6px);
  height: calc(800px + 6px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

button {
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <body>
    <div class="MyWindow">
      <form action="#" id="myform">
        <button id="first"> Первая кнопка </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="testjs.js">
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Просто на второй клик по кнопке с id `first` происходит form submit. Это можно проверить добавив лиснер на событие `submit` для Вашего `Form`, при этом не забудьте сделать там `event.preventDefault()` и какой-то `console.log();` чтобы это увидеть.

Comment: @Simon не, не в этом дело. Там и по первой тоже типа должно....но всё равно не в этом причина

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, Вы правы

Comment: document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if(event.target.id === 'first'){
            if(document.getElementById("second") === null){
                document.getElementById("myform").innerHTML += `<button id = "second" > Вторая кнопка </button>`;
                return false;
            }
        }else if(event.target.id === 'second'){
            event.target.remove();
            return false;
        }
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы меняете html формы, а когда это происходит то все слушатели "спадают". Нужно заново вешать слушателей.

я добавил так:

```
Form.querySelector("#first").addEventListener("click", onFirstButtonClick);
```

смотрите пример полностью:

```js
let Mybutton = document.getElementById("first");
let Form = document.getElementById("myform");
let isNewButtonExist = false;
let str = `<button id = "second"  type="button"> Вторая кнопка </button>`;
let NewButton;

Mybutton.addEventListener("click", onFirstButtonClick);

function onFirstButtonClick(event) {  
  if (isNewButtonExist === false) {
    Form.innerHTML += `<button id="second"  type="button"> Вторая кнопка </button>`;
    isNewButtonExist = true;
    Form.querySelector("#first").addEventListener("click", onFirstButtonClick);
  }

  if (isNewButtonExist === true) {
    NewButton = document.getElementById("second");
    NewButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      isNewButtonExist = false;
      NewButton.remove();
      NewButton = null;
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.MyWindow {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: calc(1000px + 6px);
  height: calc(800px + 6px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

button {
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MyWindow">
  <form action="#" id="myform">
    <button id="first" type="button"> Первая кнопка </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Но это **очень кривой вариант*.. Вам нужно изучить тему [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation), как раз необходимых в тот момент, когда есть **динамически меняющийся контент**, как у вас.

А вообще, в данном конкретном случае я бы просто сразу бы добавил кнопку в html, сделал бы `display: none`, а по клику просто показывал её или скрывал... то есть без физического удаления.

#### P.S.

Также обратите внимание, что тип кнопок специально поставил `button`, потому что в ином случае по умолчанию они будут триггерить сабмит формы

Comment: Не знал, что если добавить элемент в форму, то все события спадут. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Ну тут получается как ... добавление идет через html через конкатенацию строк.....а строка имутабельна, в итоге чтобы получить новую строку - нужно скопировать старую плюс добавить новую....в итоге новая строка создаётся, а слушателей там уже тю тю.....